# What is a Symbiotic Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Symbiotic Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Symbiotic Words™ | Not Symbiotic Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| GOOGOL | THOUSAND |
| POKEMON | NINTENDO |
| ANIMAL | HUMAN |
| DESK | TABLE |
| TEXTURE | MATERIAL |
| DEPENDENT | INDEPENDENT |
| EMPIRE | KINGDOM |
| DEFENSE | OFFENSE |
| SERIES | PARALLEL |
| FAMILIAR | UNFAMILIAR |

CSV Version:

```
Symbiotic Words™,Not Symbiotic Words™
GOOGOL,THOUSAND
POKEMON,NINTENDO
ANIMAL,HUMAN
DESK,TABLE
TEXTURE,MATERIAL
DEPENDENT,INDEPENDENT
EMPIRE,KINGDOM
DEFENSE,OFFENSE
SERIES,PARALLEL
FAMILIAR,UNFAMILIAR
```

These are not the only examples of Symbiotic Words™, many more exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A word is Symbiotic™ if it

> has one or more vowels,

and

> taken as a sequence, the vowels form a [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome).

For example, *REIFIED* is Symbiotic™

> because the vowels are *EIIE*, a palindrome,

while *REIFY* is not,

> because the vowels are *EI*, which is not a palindrome.

The words are called Symbiotic™ because

> the vowels in *SYMBIOTIC*, *IOI*, form a palindrome of the kind indicated.

Comment: Correct! Great job!